# Stop docker container based on public port using ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I am trying to create a ansible-playbook which can stop docker container which is running on a specific port.

From what I found online it seems we can get all the containers using

```
  tasks:
 - name: Get running containers
   docker_host_info:
    containers: yes
   register: docker_info
```

and stop container using

```
 - name: Stop running containers
   docker_container:
    name: "<container on port 8080>"
    state: stopped
```

But how can I stop a container which is running on port 8080

Comment: The use of `- debug: var=docker_info` will help you identify the data that is returning from `docker_host_info` in order to identify the filter expression required to select the container that is listening on your desired port; according to the fine manual, you may need to add [`verbose_output: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/docker_host_info_module.html#parameter-verbose_output) to get the whole story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some one else stumbles across this question, here is how I did it

```
tasks:
 - name: Get docker Info
   docker_host_info:
    containers: yes
   register: docker_info

 - name: Stop the container running on port 8080
   docker_container:
    name: "{{ docker_info | dict2items | json_query('[?key==`containers`].value[] | [?Ports[?PublicPort==`8080`]] | [0].Id') }}"
    state: stopped
```